# SHA512 to String, PHP

Tags: php, sha512

I would like to ask how to convert SHA512 to String?

```
<?php
 
$shatest = ("Erl");
$sha512test = hash("sha512",$shatest);

echo $sha512test;

?>
```

Output: 7bce51762913cd5f8c748c061dcfc5f75a2ca9b8e46372f9ebf9ec9e7450180ce5735a21d23860e945b5935ed89d7d851d30a6ab5ae765d09f4282553f9cf4f3

I would like to convert the output: (7bce51762913cd5f8c748c061dcfc5f75a2ca9b8e46372f9ebf9ec9e7450180ce5735a21d23860e945b5935ed89d7d851d30a6ab5ae765d09f4282553f9cf4f3) to string.

Please help thanks.

Comment: Seems from the manual that hash() called as you do already returns a string. (7bce... is a perfectly valid string). Could you give an example of what you're actually expecting as an output?

Comment: I just want to simple convert back the output to it`s original string which is (Erl).

Because I am planning to store the hash code to my database.

Comment: One major reason to use a hash is that it cannot be converted back to the original, if someone gets access to the hashed password, you don't want them to be able to convert it back to the original password. What you usually do when you store it to a database is to store the hash, then when the user tries to log in, you hash what they enter for a password and _compare the hash_ against what is in the database. That way, you only need to be able to convert it one way, never back to a password.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ok.. now I get it.. haha.. my bad hashing all my database value xD

Comment: it can not be converted back to the original string, as Hashes cannot be decrypted, as they are not encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type for the hash function in php is a string. That long sequence of characters representing the sha512 hash value of "Erl" is a string. So the variable $sha512test *is* already a string.

Comment: I just want to convert the output (hashed value)

Like what a sha512 converter websites doing...